# shared queue between threads in different child processes

Tags: multithreading, perl, unix

I have N fork()ed processes with M threads each (but of course, how else?). The threads are supposed to wait for jobs being submitted into some queue and eventually post some results within the same queue. All threads have the same priority and respect the same data flow (deque() a task, enque() it's results as a list of new tasks). How should I proceed with the queue implementation?

I tried a quick rewrite of a [Thread::Queue](http://search.cpan.org/~jdhedden/Thread-Queue-2.12/lib/Thread/Queue.pm) using an [IPC::Shareable](http://search.cpan.org/~msouth/IPC-Shareable-0.61/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm) as a [@queue](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDHEDDEN/Thread-Queue-2.12/lib/Thread/Queue.pm), with [enqueue()/dequeue()](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDHEDDEN/Thread-Queue-2.12/lib/Thread/Queue.pm) using a two-level (thread/process) lock,  but it turned out to be wrong (can't really [:share](http://search.cpan.org/~jdhedden/threads-shared-1.42/lib/threads/shared.pm) [IPC::Shareable](http://search.cpan.org/~msouth/IPC-Shareable-0.61/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm)'s tied array). I guess I did not want to have each thread carrying its own [IPC::Shareable](http://search.cpan.org/~msouth/IPC-Shareable-0.61/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm) instance (without thinking too much)?

Should I just freeze/thaw the tasks over an [IPC::Msg](http://search.cpan.org/~mhx/IPC-SysV-2.03/lib/IPC/Msg.pm) and implement the locks and CVs with semaphores, keeping per-thread [IPC::Msg](http://search.cpan.org/~mhx/IPC-SysV-2.03/lib/IPC/Msg.pm) instances? It sounds pretty weird to directly instantiate IPC primitives within a thread (hence my attempt to :share IPC::Shareables at thread level).

Have some of you monks did it proper and sound same time? A flat implementation, with no middleware queue managers and such? Can you please share a thought, maybe a module?

Thanks!

P.S. I'd rather not opt for a heavy existing implementation like mpi, rabbitmq, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp qw/croak/;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use insert::your::queue::impl::here;     

que_make_init();

my $numthreads = 4;
my $numprocs = 4;

sub runthreads 
{
    foreach (1..$numthreads) {
    @retcodes = map { $_->join } threads->create( sub {
        my $q = que_get_process_level_shared_instance();
        while ( (my $task = @q->get())) {
            @q->put(process($task));
        }
    });
    }
    #do_something(@retcodes) ...
    exit(0);

}

my %proctable = map {
        croak unless defined (my $pid = fork());
        runthreads if $pid == 0;
        $pid => -1;
    } (0..$numprocs-1);

#waitpid(), etc
__END__
```

Comment: Why the rewrite of `Thread::Queue`? Couldn't you just use it?

Comment: @OlafDietsche between fork()s ?

Comment: @Olaf, no, he can't. The queue is either shared between threads (not processes) or between processes (using `use forks;`, but that would prevent the creation of threads).

Comment: I'd reflect on whether it's really worth it to have multiple threads and multiple processes. If it is, how about an existing distributed computing solution (e.g. [Gearman::Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Gearman::Client))? Sounds like you're ok with a worker model.

Comment: @ikegami: or rabbitmq, or mpi. all too heavy for such a simple task (apparently)

Comment: Then one would argue so is the system you present... Why do you need such complexity?

Comment: Anyway, [shared storage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Shareable) + a [blocking signaling system](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Semaphore) is all that's needed to create the queue. Actually, it can probably be done using IPC::Shareable alone, using locks as the blocking signaling system.

Comment: @ikegami: right, I was just trying to reuse a per-process queue instance proper at thread level? it just makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cache::FastMmap. Use the same share_file in each of your threads/process and you are good.

Form POD:

"A shared memory cache through an mmap'ed file. It's core is written in C for performance. It uses fcntl locking to ensure multiple processes can safely access the cache at the same time."

```
my $Cache = Cache::FastMmap->new(raw_values => 1, share_file => "/tmp/shared_file.shm");
```